# QT QProcess memory management

Tags: qt, memory-management

If I use this in my program to start a ffmpeg command.

```
QProcess *cmd1 = new QProcess();

cmd1->start(ffmpeg command);

if (!cmd1->waitForStarted())
    return false;

if (!cmd1->waitForFinished())
return false;
```

then on finishing process will memory be deallocated of its own from heap or I have to use

delete cmd1.

Comment: You have to delete your `QProcess` yourself. Calling `cmd1->deleteLater()` will also work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set Parent to QProcess like below, then you dont need to delete it manually.

Parent can be the QObject who is creating the QProcess.

```
QProcess *cmd1 = new QProcess(parent);
```

But if you can not set parent then you need to delete it.

Comment: It might still an issue though if the parent is an object with the lifetime of the application, but starts a lot of processes. Then the QProcess objects won't be deleted until the parent is deleted, e.g. on application quit. IIn such cases one better cleans up immediately.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, or in addition you can set the process to delete itself when it is finished: -

```
// using Qt 5 connect syntax
connect(cmd1, &QProcess::finished, cmd1, &QProcess::deleteLater);
```

This is probably the preferred method, if the parent object that you pass to your QProcess object is likely to have a much longer lifetime than the QProcess object requires.

Comment: Is it worth deleting the process? If you have a real-time application, which is not running for hours, maybe it would be even better from the perspective of performance to not delete.